# ERROR: cuvid requested, but not all dependencies are satisfied: cuda/ffnvcodec

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, cuda

I am trying to compile FFMPEG with Nvidia Cuda support, on Debian 9.3. Parameters, what I am using:

```
--enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-nvenc --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --disable-x86asm --enable-libx265 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-nonfree
```

Nvidia Cuda with drivers are installed. When I try to configure ffmpeg, it says:

```
ERROR: cuvid requested, but not all dependencies are satisfied: cuda
```

Newer ffmpeg will show a similar, re-worded message:

```
ERROR: cuda requested, but not all dependencies are satisfied: ffnvcodec
```

I absolutely don't know why I'm having this issue, because I am compiling `ffmpeg` on all of our trans-coding servers.

Comment: What does config.log say towards the end? It will be in ffbuild/

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The NVIDIA headers were moved out of the FFmpeg codebase to a [standalone repository](https://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg/nv-codec-headers.git) in commit [27cbbbb](https://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commit;h=27cbbbb33f259de7c795d2b75edf7b240f0f82e6). From the commit message:

> External headers are no longer welcome in the ffmpeg codebase because
>   they increase the maintenance burden. However, in the NVidia case the
>   vanilla headers need some modifications to be usable in ffmpeg
>   therefore we still provide them, but in a separate repository.

Also, from [FFmpeg Wiki: HWAccelIntro](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro#NVENC):

> FFmpeg now uses its own slightly modified runtime-loader for nvidias
>   CUDA/nvenc/nvdec related libraries. If you get an error from configure
>   complaining about missing ffnvcodec, [this](https://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg/nv-codec-headers.git;a=summary) is what you need.
>
> It has a working `Makefile` with an install target:
>
> ```
> make install PREFIX=/usr
> ```
>
> FFmpeg will look for its `pkg-config` file, called
>   `ffnvcodec.pc`. Make sure it is in your `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`.

To compile the FFmpeg NVIDIA headers ("ffnvcodec"):

```
git clone https://git.videolan.org/git/ffmpeg/nv-codec-headers.git
cd nv-codec-headers
make
sudo make install
```

Now compile `ffmpeg` as usual. The headers should be autodetected. If not then declare the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` pointing to the path where `ffnvcodec.pc` is located when running `configure` for FFmpeg. For example:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/path/to/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure
```

Answer (score 8):

I encountered a similar error but it turns out, it was caused by missing tool package config. On Ubuntu 16.04 you can run

```
apt-get install pkgconf
```

and check whether the missing package is really missed or not:

```
pkgconf --list-all | grep package-name
```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks!

Comment: Still holds true on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 2):

This can arise due to a version mismatch between nv-codec-headers and FFmpeg. Cause: I followed specific instructions which pinned nv-codec-headers to n8.2.15.8 but left FFmpeg at master.

Starting with tag n4.4 FFmpeg requires the `CUVIDAV1PICPARAMS` struct. This is only found in dynlink_cuviddec.h of  nv-codec-headers starting with tag n11.0.10.0.

I successfully configured/compiled with nv-codec-headers `n11.1.5.1` and FFmpeg `n5.1.2` for CUDA 11.4 in an Ubuntu 18.04LTS nvidia-docker image (additional arguments/env. vars. needed:
`PKG_CONFIG_PATH="<path_to_ffnvcodec.pc_folder>"` and `--nvccflags="-gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 -O2"` )

Comment: I downgrade to version 11.1 and driver 490, ffmpeg 4.4, it works! thanks a lot

Answer (score -2):

https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/27cbbbb33f259de7c795d2b75edf7b240f0f82e6

I found this commit code occur error. Use previous commit code

git clone https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg.git

git checkout 7414d0bda7763f9bd69c26c068e482ab297c1c96

git reset --hard

Comment: This will limit you to be stuck with commit `7414d0b` indefinitely. Just download and install the NVIDIA headers before compiling `ffmpeg`.