# ffmpeg compile error with Nvidia Cuda 9.0

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, nvidia-graphics-card, centos-7, cuda

I'm compiling ffmpeg on Centos7, Nvidia driver 384.81, CUDA 9.0. I'm using a Tesla P4.

Here is my config line:

```
./configure --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-nvenc --enable-nonfree --enable-libnpp --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR: cuvid requested, but not all dependencies are satisfied: cuda
```

I found some recent info on this issue at:  [click here](https://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commit;h=27cbbbb33f259de7c795d2b75edf7b240f0f82e6)

so I did this:

```
git clone https://git.videolan.org/git/ffmpeg/nv-codec-headers.git
make
sudo make install
```

output looks like this:

```
sed 's#@@PREFIX@@#/usr/local#' ffnvcodec.pc.in > ffnvcodec.pc
install -m 0755 -d '/usr/local/include/ffnvcodec'
install -m 0644 include/ffnvcodec/*.h '/usr/local/include/ffnvcodec'
install -m 0755 -d '/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig'
install -m 0644 ffnvcodec.pc '/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig'
```

Then I try to configure ffmpeg again and I get the same error.

```
ERROR: cuvid requested, but not all dependencies are satisfied: cuda
```

Is this header fix only for cuda 8.0 or should it work with 9.0 also? Does anyone have a way to resolve this?

Comment: Try it without `--extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64`.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried that and got: ERROR: libnpp not found

Comment: I tried removing --enable-libnpp and got the original error again: `ERROR: cuvid requested, but not all dependencies are satisfied: cuda`

Comment: I got this working. I followed the newly update info here: (https://superuser.com/questions/1299064/error-cuvid-requested-but-not-all-dependencies-are-satisfied-cuda)

Comment: Ok. Good to hear it worked (I can't actually test it fully as I don't have the proper hardware). Will mark as a duplicate.