# configure not finding ffnvcodec dependency

Tags: ffmpeg, compile, cuda, configure

When running

```
    ./configure --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-nvenc --enable-nonfree --enable-libnpp --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib
```

I am met with

```
    ERROR: cuda requested, but not all dependencies are satisfied: ffnvcodec
```

even though I have cloned the external Nvidia headers repo at https://git.videolan.org/git/ffmpeg/nv-codec-headers.git, and run make & make install.

Make install puts ffnvcodec.pc in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/, which is listed when I run

```
    pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config
```

PKG_CONFIG_PATH was not set by default, but I tried exporting the output of the above command to PKG_CONFIG_PATH.

None of this has worked though. I am on macOS. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Related to [ERROR: cuvid requested, but not all dependencies are satisfied: cuda/ffnvcodec](https://superuser.com/q/1299064/110524), but it appears you tried the right things. Perhaps the latter part of `ffbuild/config.log` will be informative.

Comment: I was hoping you would appear, @LordNeckbeard. There is too much to include here from the log file, but it is not very informative. Nothing seems wrong with ffnvcodec until the end, where it spits out that error.

Comment: @Danny Did you find a solution?