# ERROR: cuda requested, but not all dependencies are satisfied: ffnvcodec

Tags: ffmpeg, gpu

I am trying to compile FFMPEG with Nvidia Cuda support on jetson TX2 by following the tutorial https://developer.nvidia.com/ffmpeg

```
git clone https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg -b master 
cd FFmpeg
./configure --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-nvenc --enable-nonfree --enable-libnpp  --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64
```

When I try to configure ffmpeg, it says:

```
ERROR: cuda requested, but not all dependencies are satisfied: ffnvcodec
```

I saw the first answer of the question :[ERROR: cuvid requested, but not all dependencies are satisfied: cuda/ffnvcodec](https://superuser.com/questions/1299064/error-cuvid-requested-but-not-all-dependencies-are-satisfied-cuda-ffnvcodec)

I thought I found the solution for my problem. To compile the FFmpeg NVIDIA headers ("ffnvcodec"):

```
git clone https://git.videolan.org/git/ffmpeg/nv-codec-headers.git
cd nv-codec-headers
make
sudo make install
```

i tried to recompile the ffmpeg as first, but i get the same error.

Then I declare the **PKG_CONFIG_PATH** pointing to the path where ffnvcodec.pc is located when running configure for FFmpeg

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/home/nvidia/ffmpeg_sources/nv-codec-headers/" ./configure --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-nvenc --enable-nonfree --enable-libnpp  --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64
```

**ERROR: cuda requested, but not all dependencies are satisfied: ffnvcodec**

thanks for any help

Comment: Try `cd FFmpeg && make distclean; ./configure --enable-nonfree --enable-libnpp`.  `--enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-nvenc` are autodetcted and are not needed. You probably don't have anything in `/usr/local/cuda/`. You likely do not need to use `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`.

Comment: @llogan Thanks. I just tried that and got: **ERROR: libnpp not found**  . you say that I have anything /usr/local/cuda but I have all libraries , you can see `nvidia@tegra-ubuntu:~$ ls /usr/local/cuda ->
bin  extras   lib64    nvml  README   share    tools
doc  include  LICENSE  nvvm  samples  targets  version.txt
`

Comment: @llogan as you say .I compile the FFmpeg NVIDIA headers and I found it -> `nvidia@tegra-ubuntu:~$ ls /usr/lib/pkgconfig ->                         
cuda-9.0.pc      mpi-c.pc            nppig-9.0.pc       ompi-cxx.pc   cufft-9.0.pc     mpi-fort.pc         nppist-9.0.pc      ompi.pc
cuinj64-9.0.pc   nppc-9.0.pc         nppitc-9.0.pc      pm-utils.pc
cusolver-9.0.pc  nppial-9.0.pc       nvgraph-9.0.pc     visionworks.pc
cusparse-9.0.pc  nppicc-9.0.pc       nvml-9.0.pc        vpx.pc
ffnvcodec.pc     nppicom-9.0.pc      nvrtc-9.0.pc

`  . but the problem is not resolved yet

Comment: @llogan 
since I installed cuda 9.0, I found another folder **/cuda9.0/** and **/cuda/** in the directory **/usr/local**
so I have to try again with ->  `./configure --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-nvenc --enable-nonfree --enable-libnpp --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda-9.0/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda-9.0/lib64ERROR: cuda requested, but not all dependencies are satisfied: ffnvcodec`

**but it still does not work !**

Comment: FFMpeg support is not supported by TX2 just like for desktop GPUshttps://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1002969/jetson-tx2/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-harware-acceleration-on-tx2-/post/5275574/#5275574

Comment: You can make that as an answer.

Comment: You can use `make install PREFIX=$HOME/ffmpeg_build` (for example) if you don't want to install to /usr/local.